# B+ tree in C++ with malloc()

Tags: c++, pointers, malloc

I have a question about B+ tree implementation with C++ (qt). I have a node struct like

```
struct node{
    int keys[MAX_KEY];
    int numberOfKeys = 0;
    node *pointer[MAX_KEY + 1];
    bool isLeaf = false;
    node *next = NULL;
    node *pre = NULL;
    node *parent = NULL;
};
```

and I wanna allocate a memory block for first node with this code part:

```
node*  pnt  =  (node*)  malloc(sizeof(node));
```

For other added nodes later than this, I want to achieve them with using `pnt`'s address. How can I do that?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [FAQ] soon. If you're using C++, using `malloc()` is not a good idea.  Use `new` et al, or techniques that use `new` under the covers.

Comment: thanks :) i have no idea how to point each node to another with "new"

Comment: You could add one or more constructors to the class (a `struct` is a `class` with all variables public by default), and one of the constructors will take a `node *` argument which is the parent node, and it will initialize the new node with the correct value in the parent member. You could default the argument to 0 (or `nullptr`) so that invoking the constructor without an argument will create a new root node, or you could have a separate factory function for doing that. When you need to create a child node for a given existing node, you pass the parent node pointer to the constructor.

Comment: thanks for your response, i will try it soon.

Answer (score 0):

You want to make a class something like this

```
class BTree {
public:
    BTree();
    ~BTree();
    void insert( int, void * ptr );
    void * find( int );
private:
    struct node * root;
};
```

Filling in the methods is your job.